# File upload form not working

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to make a simple form to upload files, but it doesn't do anything and sends me an `Uncaught ReferenceError: files is not defined at javascript.js:1` error. Any help?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

And the script:

```
var numFiles = files.length;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    event.preventDefault();
    var fileName = e.target.files[numFiles].name;
    alert(fileName);
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you think `files` is?

Comment: @AjAX. According to MDM it's a list of files uploaded

Comment: What is MDM then?

Comment: @AjAX. Mozilla's web documentation

Comment: It is **MDN** then. But where is it in your `script`?

Comment: @AjAX. It doesn't go in the script because it's part of FileAPI, which comes with HTML5